# Error with persistent volume on NFS

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm learning about pv and pvc in Kubernetes,

- I'm using minikube with one node
- I run NFS service on my laptop, and exported correctly
- I can mount the NFS exports inside minikube, run minikube ssh then inside it mount mylaptopIP:/nfs-export-dir /mount-dir-in-minikube and successfully read and write to it
- followed this tutorial "https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-nfs-persistent-volume-kubernetes/", create the pv and the pvc successfully and the status is "Bound", but the pod status is "ContainerCreating", the events shows this error "mount failed: exit status 32..."

I have searched but all the answers directing me to install the nfs-common on the working node, which is the same control node in my case, and it is installed, and I can successfully mount  the remote NFS exports

What's wrong? And how I can fix it?